# itemMarginLeft or itemMarginRight options in HighCharts legend?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

So Right now according to the documents in `legend` there're options of `itemMarginLeft` and `itemMarginRight`, but is there able to modify left or right margin? when I enlarge the symbol the margin seem to be match with the original symbol size but not adopt to the modified size.

```
    legend: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42)',
      borderRadius: 5,
      itemDistance: 90,
      itemMarginTop: 5,
      itemMarginBottom: 5,
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#C0D3DE',
        fontSize: '16px',
        fontFamily: 'Fira Sans',
      },
      symbolHeight: 25,
      symbolWidth: 5,
      symbolRadius: 30,
      symbolPadding: 15,
    },
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cz9dpLv/3/

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @KamilKulig here you go.

Comment: Sorry for an inaccurate request. Please provide the code necessary to recreate your legend (live demo on jsfiddle would be ideal). The code that you've provided produces the following result: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7cz9dpLv/

Comment: @KamilKulig lol, I updated the jsfiddle

Comment: I managed to achieve the following result by adjusting the value of `symbolWidth` and `padding`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/humkawfd/ Is that the desired result?

Comment: @KamilKulig YES!! Thank you!